# Obtain the NSEntityDescription of an NSManagedObject from a class method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject, class-method

I'm adding a few class methods to `NSManagedObject` and in one of them I need to obtain the `NSEntityDescription` of it. Problem is, `entity` is an instance method and I don't know how to access it from a class method.

Is there any way of doing this, short of creating a dummy instance just for accessing this property? Sounds like a horrible hack...

Answer (score 4):

`NSManagedObject` class can't know about `NSEntityDescription` simply because there's no `entity` at class level. Look at `- (instancetype)initWithEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity
insertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context`; after you initialise it with an entity description you will be able to retrieve it, from an instance of course.

One way to achieve what you are describing would be having a `NSManagedObject` subclass for your Core Data entity (which is a recommended approach) and having a class method `+ (NSString)entityName` which will return a string representing the entity name in your Core Data model.

```
+ (NSString *)entityName {
    return @"MyEntity";
}
```

If we assume that the class name and the entity name are the same you could do:

```
+ (NSString *)entityName {
    return NSStringFromClass(self);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: And in fact, if you use [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) to generate your managed object classes, it creates those convenience methods for you.

Comment: There is a new class Method starting with macOS 10.12 and iOS 10: `class func entity() -> NSEntityDescription` https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1640588-entity